# What does "failed (Result: resources)" mean in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd unit which failed, and I'm not sure what the result type is supposed to mean.

```
Active: failed (Result: resources) since Thu 2016-11-17 21:06:42 UTC; 32min ago
```

What does `Result: resources` mean? I'm familiar with `Result: exit-code`, but not this one.

Comment: You have run out of resources to start the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that it is quite generic error message. Since I am not sure when you get this message I am sending you the necessary information so you can find it yourself but it can be the interpretation of errnos of system calls, ex `ENOMEM`.

Follow `SERVICE_FAILURE_RESOURCES` in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/2e6dbc0fcd45c152f15aed77cde4fd07957c150c/src/core/service.c.

Comment: Thanks for this. I looked into the source and it seems that it's a generic failure message, which is definitely not helpful given that I didn't even get any journalctl messages... https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/7d78f7cea82dc7b4ced77f86a05124add2509390/src/core/service.h#L83 "a bit of a misnomer, just our catch-all error for errnos we didn't expect"

Comment: Notice that before going in to this state, we always print out something to the syslogs where we should be printing something about the error code. Example, https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/2e6dbc0fcd45c152f15aed77cde4fd07957c150c/src/core/service.c#L1941

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this helps, but I got this message on Ubuntu when I placed the .service files under **/etc/systemd/system**.
After obtaining a directory listing, I noticed that there weren't any individual service files there. Everything was either links to service files udner **/lib/systemd/system**, or directories like *paths.target.wants* - ending on *.wants*

Will post an update, if I manage to resolve this. It appears I need to

1. Move the .service files under **/lib/systemd/system**
2. Create symlinks from **/etc/systemd/system** pointing to **/lib/systemd/system**

===

OK, solved it. I did (1) and (2) above, but that was not the issue. In one of my Unit files, in the [Service] section I have:

**EnvironmentFile=/etc/concourse/web_env**

Well, turned out I created the /etc/concourse directory, but did NOT move the **web_env** configuration file, which the cocnourse-web.service needs to function properly. Hence, "**resources**" ... error in systemd, because the service (in this case Concourse CI Web Node) *could not find* its **web_env** configuration file.

Hope this helps you solve your issue, and good luck, of course.
Here is a screenshot for more clarity: [image: Unit file for Concourse Web Node]

Comment: There weren't any individual service files because _you_ haven't placed any of them there. That's literally the purpose of /etc/systemd – to hold custom local services, not to hold packaged services (which go in /lib).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I created the service manually, but I guess the tutorial I was following was wrong. Normally, with packaged software, the package manager copies service files in the proper locations.

Comment: Here is a link to the tutorial: https://serverspace.us/support/help/installing-concourse-ci/. Notice there is line that reads:
vim /etc/systemd/system/concourse-web.service
In a bizarre manner, the author also tries to start a systemctl service with "service start"

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake of not putting the env file in the right path while also configuring a concourse worker on a VM, what are the chances :)